# Select button with options style in PURE CSS

Tags: html, css

I want attractive style for Select button & option tags with hover effect without JS:

i am finding difficulties in changing the color of option below are the codes:

HTML:

```
    <select id="dept" > <option value="0" selected="">All</option>
                                <option value="6">2010</option>
                                <option value="5">2011</option>
                                <option value="4">2013</option>
                                <option value="3">2014</option>
                                <option value="2">2015</option>
                                <option value="1">2017</option>
                            </select>
```

Comment: you can try bootsrap UI or Material UI for this

Comment: It is not possible to style select elements cross-browser since they are generally native OS controls.